# Is there a way to check that the parameters passed to a function are non-null in a pseudocode?

Tags: c, python-3.x, pseudocode

I want to write something similar to assert(variable_name) in a C function in my pseudocode, to check that the parameters I am passing to the function are valid/non-null. How to specify it in my pseudocode? Do I define it as a precondition? If so, how to define it? My function is as follows and I need to check if values have been assigned to the variables i and j.

```
return_type function V1(parameters : i, j)
assert(i)    //how to write this in pseudocode?
assert(j)     //how to write this in pseudocode?
```

Comment: Why not `if (!i)` and `if (!j)` then they are NULL? (that's valid code, not just psuedocode) For pseudocode `assert(i)` and `assert(j)` are fine and quite clear. You could just write `i != NULL` and `j != NULL` as well for pseudocode.

Comment: It's pseudocode; you can do whatever you like to indicate it. Maybe look into Eiffel and other design-by-contract languages for ideas?

Comment: Hmm... For me this would depend on the intended usecase. For example, if an exception state raised by the possible failed assertion is important to the pseudocode, then maybe an `if (i is null) then throw exception` would be appropriate.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin However, correct me if I am wrong here, but won't using "assert" kind of take away from the universality of the pseudocode because as far as I am aware not every programming language uses a built in assert statement? I apologise if I have wrong or incomplete information about this though since I'm quite new to writing pseudocodes and programming in general.

Comment: @Shawn thanks for the suggestion! I'll definitely look more into it..

Comment: There isn't a real "this is the pseudocode for it" reference. What you are wanting to convey is the user should validate that the pointers are not NULL. The checks or `assert()` are a couple of way, as would be `validate (i not NULL)` and the same for `j`. Up to you really.

Comment: @Jasha okay! I don't really know much about exception case blocks, but I will give them a read and keep this in mind if I do decide to add it in my pseudocode

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin oh okay! Thanks for clearing that up! I wasn't too sure if pseudocodes have some specific terminology too since upon searching the internet on how to define preconditions and postconditions in a pseudocode, I couldn't find a lot..

Comment: actually you can throw asserts in python code, but for pseudocode an assertion should be an "if" statement. There are a lot of assert methods in python , they check certain conditions. https://www.mattcrampton.com/blog/a_list_of_all_python_assert_methods/. your needed assertion would be a check: if i == Null     (some others use: if i == nil) and the same for j.